# Projection on plane

Tags: design

[image: this is front view I tried . I also want to know is front view and side view will be the same or not and in this top view will there be any dotted line?][image]How to draw the projection of this 3d image on paper ?

I have tried using methods of projection on plane which are given in ND Bhatt book.
Dimensions to be assumed by you.[image: it's projection should not look like table clock and it is same from all sides]
I have uploaded my rough try and it is front view only because I think that both side views will be same am I correct? and I am unable to make its plain view can you please provide a rough sketch for side and plain views without dimensions as I will put all the other things myself.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to: 1. Fix the title into something that tells what your question is about. (All questions on the site are about engineering design in some way.) 2. Explain what projections you want. Plan view and two elevations? 3. Show your work so far and explain where you are stuck.  Otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: Might also want to add additional tags like Drawing, Draft, Cad, etc

Comment: actually I am unable to start so please provide some hint about how to start .I use drafter and I am making these for the first time that's why I am confused .

Comment: You can consider that I have a bit knowledge about it..

Comment: please provide rough sketch or hint and further I will do

Comment: When you "*tried using methods of projection on plane which are given in ND Bhatt book*" what results did you get ? Please add your attempts also into the question.

Comment: I will add my attempts within 15 hours from now as I won't be able to post it now. Sorry for the problem please don't close the question till then. THANK YOU

Comment: Your photo is not 3D, it's a 2D projection of  an object which can as well be 3D as another 2D photo. It's impossible to decide exactly the form nor dimensions of the original.  We can guess it has (for easiest practical woodwork) quite simple straight and rectangular forms and it's symmetric, but that's only a guess. Making that guess you can sketch 2D engineering drawings, but that's shown already as an answer. Extracting the right dimensions from the photo is impossible without more assumptions or exact knowledge of the photo shooting gear & constellation.

Comment: please give me some hints more and it is plan view i.e. top view istead of plain view in the question

Comment: The top view is just what you would see if you looked down from the top. Draw the plan view of the top block, then the next section down, etc. Post your attempt. Have you got any Lego bricks or wooden blocks? If so then build a model and take front, side and top view photos and study them!

Comment: I have added my try of top view . Please clear the difference between front view and side view?

Comment: Side and front view will be the same for this bulding

Comment: Can u please tell me what is that given in answer no. 2? Is my front and top view correct?

Comment: You are missing the brick wall under the clock, but you basically have the top level correct

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are asking? Below is a start.

[image]

Comment: I will try with this start and will ask if there is any doubt and will post my previous try too

Comment: It's side view looks same as front view . Can you please clarify am I thinking correct?

Comment: Yes. In this case - a square tower (evident by the top view), all sides (front, back, left, and right side) are the same. As long as you know how to utilize the extension (dashed) lines, and draw a perpendicular baseline, then everything is getting simple, just taking a lot of measurements.

Comment: How to know it's HP and VP as I think they are required to make a perfect drawing ?

Comment: What is HP, VP? Are you talking about 3D view? It is a completely different matter then.

Comment: vertical plane and horizontal plane same as that given in ND Bhatt in projection of planes topic

Comment: I 'don't know his work, but I guess the "vertical plane" means the 4 side views (elevation view), and the "horizontal view" is the top and bottom views (plan view). The 6 views define a 3D (three-dimensional) element.

Comment: If this is the case, then when you standing in front of the tower, you are facing the vertical front view; when you are located above the roof and looking down, you see the top horizontal plan view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an automated way what you would need to use is research **homography** (this is very close to the [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) which they also might be of help).

This is too broad to cover here (and I am not sure that its directly relevant to what you are asking) so I will just provide some links and also what you can accomplish.

### What you can accomplish

Below are two images from the documentaion of [opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org). The initial image is a warped photo of some windows (is similar to the example in the image). The aim is to transform the image and bring the windows perpendicular to the projection plane (which can be seen in the end result).

| Initial image | end result |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

**Figure **source: [docs.opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html))**

The way this is accomplished is by finding the four corners of the yellow closed **polygon** on the left, and map those points to the **rectangle** on the right. A transformation matrix is calculated from these 4 points (that's close to magic) and from that point on you can map every other pixel in the image and produce the end result on the right.

**Caveat**:in your case the lower side of the clock is not visible so this algorithm will produce an ugly effect.

### Links

- [Opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html)
- [Learn OpenCV](https://learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/)
- [Matlab focused question on Signal processing Stack](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/how-to-apply-a-2d-2d-homography-matrix-to-an-image)

Comment: sorry but I don't know much about the topic I just know that written in ND Bhatt book . I have just started studying this.